# Use DataColumn values as source for ValueList on UltraGridColumn

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

Is there a way I can use a DataColumn from a DataTable as the `ValueList` for an UltraGrid column?

I have the column style set to `DropDownList`. The question is, what do I use for `ValueList`?

```
ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["col"].Style = ColumnStyle.DropDownList;
ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["col"].ValueList = ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [BindableValueList](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.BindableValueList_members.html).  One of the [Constructors](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.BindableValueList~_ctor%28Object,String,String,String,Control%29.html) takes the object for the datasource, the dataMember, the displayMember, valueMember, and bindingContextControl.

The line of code to set the ValueList:

```
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["col"].ValueList = new BindableValueList(dt, "", "displayColumn","valueColumn", this.ultraGrid1);
```

In the above example, dt is the DataTable you are binding to, displayColumn and valueColumn would be the keys for the columns that you want to use as the display and value portions of the drop down.  If you are binding to a DataSet and want to bind to a table other than the first table you would use the second parameter to pass in the name of the table to bind to.

Comment: +1 never used that. Looks better indeed, however the OP asked for just one column without the ValueColumn.

Comment: I am not sure how you would only use one column since you need the value and the display portion of the value list unless they were the same and the display is the same as the value.  If they are the same then you could specify the same column for both.

Comment: Actually in my code I have used the ValueListItems.Add overload that wants two parameters (datavalue and displaytext) however there is also an overload that accepts only the displaytext http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.ValueListItemsCollection~Add(Object).html

Comment: The overload actually takes the dataValue and automatically sets the DisplayText to be a string representation of the data value when using that overload which would be similar to binding both to the same item from the DataTable.

Comment: Thanks alhalama.I wanted to ask there are two columns in ultragrid.first column style is checkbox.second valuelist.so, how to get second column value where first column is checked.

Comment: Assuming that your grid is bound to a DataTable, the data is in a DataTable so you could create a DataView for that table and set the RowFilter property of the DataView so that it returns only those that are checked.  Or if you are bound to a list, you could use linq to get a list of the objects that are checked.

Answer (score 0):

This could be of help. It a simple procedure that receives a DataTable, the value for the Key property of the ValueList and the name of the field to use as list for the the ValueList and returns a Value list to set in one of your UltraGridColums

```
    public ValueList DataTableToValueList(DataTable dt, string vlKey, string fieldName)
    {
        ValueList vl = new ValueList();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vlKey)) vl.Key = vlKey;
        foreach (DataRowView r in dt.DefaultView)
            vl.ValueListItems.Add(r[fieldName]);
        return vl;
    }
```

use in this way (probably in the InitializeLayout event)

```
    grd.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["col"].ValueList = 
                    DataTableToValueList(dtCustomers,"vlCustomer", "CustomerName");
```

Comment: It would be simpler just to use a BindableValueList.